# call a function N times by write N parentheses after the function

Tags: c++

I want to implement the following:

I define a function. And when I write *N* `()`'s after the function, the function will be called *N* times.

I give an example：

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void* (*c)();
typedef c (*b)();
typedef b (*a)();

a aaa()
{
    cout<<"Google"<<endl;

    return (a)aaa;
}

int main()
{
    aaa()()()();
    system("pause");
}
```

Then the output is :

[image]

Are there any other methods to implement that?

Comment: You could use a functor by overloading the `()`-operator for a class and return the instance of the object.

Comment: `std::cout << 'a' << 'b' << 'c' << 'd' << 'e' << 'f' << 'g' << ...`

Comment: I see answers with functors popping up, which would also be the way I'd solve it (supposing I'd really wanted to do this in the first place). But out of interest -- are there any ways to do this with _functions_ only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple using functors.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Function
{
   Function& operator()() {
      std::cout << "Google" << std::endl;
      return *this;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Function f;
   f()()()();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in functors:

```
#include <iostream>

class my_functor {
    public:
    //  if called without parameters
        my_functor& operator()(){
            std::cout << "print" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
    //  if called with int parameter
        my_functor& operator()(int number){
            std::cout << number << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main(){
    my_functor functor;
    functor()(5)();
    return 0;
}
```

By overloading the function call operator `()` you can add function-behaviour to your object. You can also define different parameters which shall be passed to your overloaded `()`-operator and the respective function call will be invoked. Just make sure that you return a reference to this-instance, if you want to invoke the function call on the object instance, that was modified by the previous function call.